# Multiple jQuery panel slides

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm new to jQuery and have been following the tutorial here for a Panel Slide.
http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/jquery-tutorials-for-designers/all-comments/#comments

So far so good.

Though I require a number of panel slides. The page is going to look very similar to this
woothemes.com/themes/

When you click an image a 100% width panel will expand under the row to reveal further information.

I was just wondering if there's an alternative to using unique classes for each different image?

Hope that made sense.

Thanks for your help.

J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of classes, you can make use of the relative positions of the elements in the DOM.

A simple example is to have images followed directly by panels, and make use of **[`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/)** when an image is clicked on to slide open the next sibling element.

You can put all of the images and contents into one parent div. That way you don't have to use any classes inside that parent div.

Here's a simple slider system that degrades nicely if Javascript is turned off.

Let's set up a simple example.

### The HTML:

```
<div id="sliderContent">

    <div>
        <img src="image1.jpg" />
        <div>Content about image1 here.</div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <img src="image2.jpg" />
        <div>Other content about image2 here.
             <p>You can put as much stuff in these as you want</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <img src="image3.jpg" />
        <div>Sample content about image3 her here.</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

The above content will display in a sensible fashion even if Javascript is turned off.

It's nice to have the `img`s nested in parent `div`s, since `img`s aren't block level elements, so the line breaks will be nicer with a parent `div` containing each image and content `div`.

`div`s take up 100% of the width given. You can add child divs in the content divs, you can style them, you can put `hr`s inside them, etc.

Now let's create our jQuery. It'll make all the content sliders invisible. It will also make it so that the corresponding slider is toggled if an image is clicked.

### The Script

```
$(function() {

    $("#sliderContent img").next().hide();

    $("#sliderContent img").click(function() {
        $(this).next().slideToggle();

    });
});​
```

### **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/8aD9C/)**

And that's it. Of course you can spruce things up with added graphics and colors, but the central concept is very simple.

Here is a simple way to add a close button into each content DIV. It's not good to include the close buttons in the HTML, since they are meaningless if Javascript is disabled, so we add them dynamically:

```
$(function() {

     // Hide and add a close button to each content div slider
   $("#sliderContent img").next().hide().append('<input ' + 
                                                'type="button" value="close"/>');

    $("#sliderContent img").click(function() {
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
    });

      // use .parent() to make the close buttons work
    $("input").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().slideUp();
    });
});​
```

### **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/MrFMF/)**

Comment: That's perfect! Many thanks! Though it's not working for me in Chrome or Safari... Just Firefox. Any reason in particular and any possible work around?

Comment: @Jason - Strange. It works for me in Chrome, Firefox, IE, and Safari --- Are you using this link? ==> http://jsfiddle.net/8aD9C/ --------- jQuery generally handles cross browser issues quite nicely, so usually it's a good choice for that reason.

Comment: The jsfiddle preview of yours works for me in chrome/safari - But when I go test it out myself and copy and paste it over and preview in browser I have no luck with webkit browsers. This is what I've done, pasted it all in html box so you can see it all - http://jsfiddle.net/HdWwq/ --- Have I gone wrong somewhere?

Comment: @Jason - That looks ok. And it works on all my browsers. -------- You can just right click, open in new tab on the iframe to look at the code of the page as a whole. For example, here is my original jsFiddle as simply one HTML page ==> http://fiddle.jshell.net/8aD9C/show/light/ ----------- jsFiddle sometimes triggers some security warnings because of all the iFrames (noScript blocks it w default settings, for example), so maybe that's what's going on.... try looking at just the single page.

Comment: That works! Great. Have no idea what the issue was there... Oh well. I'm happy now. Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: One last thing - If I wanted to add a little minimize button in the actual sliding panel its self to close it, how would I go about that?

Comment: Just put the button into the content `div` and use `.parent()` to close the slider when the button is clicked. You can add the close button in the HTML, or add it dynamically w JS. Here's an example ==> http://jsfiddle.net/dhazQ/

Comment: @Jason - And dynamically adding the close buttons ==> http://jsfiddle.net/Gz2e2/ ---- Edited it into the answer.